# How do I post code on Stack Overflow fast?

Tags: support, markdown, editor

I tried a lot of different ways, but the only way is manual.

I tried with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and inserted the code, but it's badly rendered, and a lot of text is not inserted into the code.

Is there some solution for this?

Comment: [Here's some more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309309/improperly-formatted-code-when-adding-an-additional-image-in-an-edit/309310#309310) on how to avoid some obstacles with posting code. But apparently didn't work for the OP at Stack Overflow specifically.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Well, there are quite a number of sites that rely on putting substantial chunks of code in the question (Code Review, SO, sometimes Software Engineering or Unix&Linux or Tex, etc).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yeah, you're probably right. The question needs more clarification about the specific problems though. _"and lot of text is not inserted into the code"_ We need a reproducible example.

Comment: Copy and paste. Faster than typing manually. Each OS has its own way to copy and paste things, e.g. in Windows it's CTRL+C for copy, and CTRL+V for pasting.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Did you not know about copy pasting text, as Shadow Wizard illustrated? Or do you actually really use ctrl-k before pasting the code, in which case you need to paste the code, select it, and *only then* format the code? Formatting code definitely works.

Comment: @Felix _"Or do you actually really use ctrl-k before pasting the code"_ I tried to address that misconception in my answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that @πάνταῥεῖ :) let's see what time says now!

Answer (score 4):

I am just used to

1. Copy my code from my currently used IDE or text editor:
   [image]
2. Paste it into the editor window
   [image]
3. (Select it when needed) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
   [image]

Here's an example of the result:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    if(true) {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

You can inspect my example results above by clicking the [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/309446/edit) button below.

> I tried with <kbd>ctrl-k</kbd> and inserting the code, ...

Be sure to do it in the order mentioned in the above steps.

---

There's a maximum number of characters you can post in a single question though. Refer here to see the details please:

- [Knowing Your Limits: What is the maximum length of a question title, post, image and links used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176447/186472)

Anyway, at Stack Overflow (and some other sites) you should try to shape your code well, to fit within the rules of a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (emphasis on minimal).

On the contrary, - at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for example -, it is allowed to post even lengthy and complete code, but maybe better split up into a sequence of related questions, if it doesn't fit into a single question (or answer) post.

Comment: yeah but when the code is very long like i said before.. lot of text is not inserted into the code

Comment: @SergioRamo There's an overall limit of characters you can use in your post. And if your code is very long, you should notice that you're supposed to post a [MCVE] (emphasis is **minimal** in this context) at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I just paste my code into a text editor, select all, double tab, copy all, and paste it into the question / answer block.

Comment: What if your code originally contains tab characters? You probably want to clean these up (convert to blanks) before inserting it into the post. Otherwise you'll be thrown with some unreadable mess. Also the difference between editor window and preview isn't easy to spot and clear for such cases. (Notepad++ is your friend)

Comment: @πανταρει good points.  Given that most of the code (terminal output) that I edit in doesn't have tabs, that didn't occur to me.

Comment: It often depends on IDE settings. Especially Visual Studio wen't with the dark side of the schwitz, and defaults to use TABS not being auto converted to blanks. On the other hand with e.g. GNU make files, TAB characters are an essential need . Anyways, in the end markup doesn't render them correctly, and need some adjustment to keep your code readable at SE sites. Not to mention that you don't need that extra step to paste in the editor. CTRL-K just works fine (unless there's a problem like I've pointed out above).

Comment: Hmmm, I just was about writing my own answer, and tested what I've mentioned about the TAB characters. They seem to render just well now (I had a different experience times ago). There seem to be some other problems the OP encountered when using CTRL-K. The question needs to be more clarified what's there actual problem.